# Error Pulling Facebook Ad Campaign

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to automate a task for my company. They want me to pull the insights from their ad campaigns and put it in a CSV file. From here I will create a excel sheet that grabs this data and automates the plots that we send to our clients.

I have referenced the example code from the library and I believe where my confusion exists is in who I define 'me' to be in line 14.

```
token = 'temporary token from facebook API'
VOCO_id = 'AppID'
AppSecret = 'AppSecret'
me = 'facebookuserID'
AppTokensDoNotExpire = 'AppToken'
from facebook_business import FacebookSession
from facebook_business import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign as AdCampaign
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccountuser import AdAccountUser as AdUser
session = FacebookSession(VOCO_id,AppSecret,AppTokensDoNotExpire)
api = FacebookAdsApi(session)
FacebookAdsApi.set_default_api(api)
me = AdUser(fbid=VOCO_id)
####my_account = me.get_ad_account()
```

When I run the following with the hashtag on my_account, I get a return stating that the status is "live" for these but the value of my permissions is not compatible.

Comment: From my research I believe I may need an account id? something starting with act_#######

Comment: `me` in Graph API refers to the entity the access token belongs to - use it with a user access token, and it will refer to that user; use it with a page access token, and it will refer to the page. (Doesn’t work with an app access token though, that would only throw an error; accessing details about an app always requires the app id.)

Comment: Would recommend that you use [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to figure out what permissions you need and what exact requests you need to make; it helps in figuring this kind of stuff out before you have to do any actual coding.

Comment: I needed to bootstrap this entire time...